# Asymptotics on the number of diffeomorphism classes in the Cheeger finiteness theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, comparison-geometry

A [result of Cheeger](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373498) says that, given any even dimension and any $\delta > 0$, there are only a finite number of diffeomorphism types of compact simply-connected manifolds of that dimension which admit Riemannian metrics with $\delta$-pinched sectional curvature (i.e. $\delta\le K ≤ 1$).

Are there any known (or conjectured) asymptotics on this number as $\delta\to 0$?

Comment: What are some examples when $\delta < \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: By [Brendle-Schoen](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3963), $\delta<\tfrac{1}{4}$ if it's not a sphere and not a symmetric space.  So any of the other examples listed in section 2 of [this survey of Ziller](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/papers/SurveyMexico.pdf) should have $\delta<\tfrac{1}{4}$.  (And some of those are even-dimensional.)

Comment: In the paper of [Stefan Peters](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1984.349.77/html) there is an upper bound of $e^{e^{2n+8}}, $ but there is another assumption on the sectional curvature.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to study this -- at first glance it's an explicit version for a different version of the Cheeger finiteness theorem than the one I asked about, but maybe there's a way of using it to answer my question.